# How can I use properties of elements within other elements in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-proptypes, react-props

Maybe it's a silly question, How can I use properties of elements within other elements?
I want to show the title of the button that they chose in different places,here is my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements'; // Version can be specified in package.json

export default class App extends Component {
  _handleButtonPress = () => {
    Alert.alert(
    {Button.title}
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Whom do you love the most in this world?  </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          {Button.title}    
        </Text>
      
      <Button
        title="Cat"
        onPress={this._handleButtonPress}
      />
    
        <Button
          title="mother in law"
          onPress={this._handleButtonPress}
        />
        
        
      <Button
        title="dog"
        onPress={this._handleButtonPress}
      />
    
        
      <Button
        title="Computer"
        onPress={this._handleButtonPress}
      />
    
      
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

In this case I want that every time they choose a button the title of the button appears in different parts, in an alert, in a list, showing the first option and the last one.

[https://snack.expo.io/@julioejurado/-whom-do-you-love-the-most?][1]

Comment: What do you mean by different places? on next screen?

Comment: Yes differnt places, I mean same screen in  {Button.title} that comes from title = 'foo'

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 ways to achieve that. One is to maintain state in component or across the app, for that look into Redux and React-Redux which is recommended.

Or you can do the following in your code:

```
<Button title={'Something here'} 
        onPress={() => this._handleButtonPress('Message to show in alert')}/>
```

And in your handler function:

```
_handlerButtonPress = message => {Alert.alert(message)}
```